# PHP Class, Interface, Inheritance

Tags: php

I am trying to understand inheritance in php. I have two classes `ShopProduct` and `CdProduct`. `ShopProduct` class have one method `getName`. `CdProduct` class inherit (extends) `ShopProduct` class and have method `DoWork`. In `index.php` file I create a one `CdProduct` object and pass it to the method that takes one parameter like this `function Work(ShopProduct $item){...}`. Now, I can understand that I can call `getName` method using `$item` parameter, and I know that I can call `DoWork` method using `$item`, but I can't understand how this is  possible... I hope I was clear... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible because the object passed as parameter happens to contain the *DoWork* method. It's risky calling this sort of methods (belonging to the inheriting class) without type-checking.

Why does it let you give a *CdProduct* parameter when the mentioned one is *ShopProduct*? Well any class derived from the *ShopProduct* will contain all its attributes and methods, thus not affecting functionality in the method body.

What can be achieved through this is having a Work method that can receive as a parameter any type derived from **ShopProduct**(*CdProduct*, *BookProduct*, *CandyProduct*) without needing a separate function for each type [*WorkCd*(CdProduct $item) or *WorkBook*(BookProduct $item)] that actually does the same thing.

If you really need access to derived-type specific methods and attributes you can do something like a switch on object class name:

```
switch(get_class($item))
{
     case "CdProduct":
        //CdProduct object specific code here
     break;
     case "BookProduct":
         //BookProduct object specific here
     break;
     //And so and so forth...
 }
```

Comment: Not all the attributes: only protected and public declared attributes.

Comment: I supposed the simplest scenario, hopefully Knight will have the pleasure and motivation to discover all the details and obscurities after understanding step 0.

Comment: Thank you guys...I understand inheritance and how it works ( with private, public and protected methods, attributes ect.), but because I previosly learned C# in which perent class cannot call children class I am a little confused.  Chiru Constantin - Alexandru you first sentence was the theme I wanted to be clarify. How perent class (ShopProduct) can call childern's method (DoWork) even through reference on children class (CdProduct)...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works is because PHP 5 introduces type hinting: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php .
So indeed **CdProduct** inherits all the public and protected methods and attributed declared in **ShopProduct** and thus you can call the **getName()** method. When you pass the CdProduct instance to the Work function which declares the first parameter to be **ShopProduct** (and not **CdProduct**) you are forcing the parameter to be casted to **ShopProduct**. 
So if you pass as parameter something different from **CdProduct** instance, like a string as an example, you have an error, but because of the inheritance this doesn't fail (it should however print a notice).

As you can read from the comments in the link posted above:

*p.s. do note: when used in inherited classes a STRICT-notice comes up, because the function definition of the inherited class doesn't match the parent's definition (different type hinting) - but it works great!*